# In VBA, how can I set an Array to Empty?

Tags: arrays, vba, is-empty

Now, before you say it - I've read dozens of similar topics, and couldn't find a solution. I have a dynamic Variant array, which has to be completely cleared, so it is regarded as Empty during IsEmpty check. I tried Erase, but IsEmpty still returns False. I can't ReDim it, because the array is dynamic. Tried to set whole array to Nothing, but that throws an error during IsEmpty check.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I completely eradicate that array, so the IsEmpty would return True?

Comment: Can you show relevant codes in your question? Edit it please.

Comment: @Raptor - FYI, `code` is [singular in this case](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/20455/282305).

Answer (score 7):

You can assign the keyword `Empty` to a Variant variable.

```
Public Sub Hello()

    Dim vArray As Variant

    vArray = Array("a", "b", "c")

    Debug.Print IsEmpty(vArray) 'prints false

    vArray = Empty

    Debug.Print IsEmpty(vArray) 'prints true

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Erase statement.

```
Erase vArray
```